# Cousin cant connect to my minecraft server because im running my server on a subnet of a wireless access point

Tags: networking, wireless-router, port-forwarding, subnet, minecraft

I'm using a **linksys router** with tomato installed as a wireless access point for my computer upstairs... But the computer downstairs cant connect to the minecraft server im hosting on the computer upstairs. The router upstairs is using a subnet with **192.168.2.xxx** and the one downstairs is **192.168.1.xxx**. My ip is **192.168.2.31** and the ip downstairs is **192.168.1.143**. Im running the minecraft server on the normal port but this computer apparently cant talk to any computers on the routers network downstairs. I'm pretty sure this is because of the subnet im using but this is the only way i could get internet upstairs. I can't connect a cable because there is no way to drill through the floor and i wont run a cable because it would need to be around 150 feet.

We're just trying to play on the same server. I've tried running his world and my world on lan but that doesn't work because im pretty sure i'd have to port forward his port given every time and that's very tedious. I'm just looking for way to do this that is reliable and will take care of itself without input every time we want to play. I've also tried running a dedicated server on my computer for minecraft but I don't know what ip to run and in which order to forward the port.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please Help!!

Comment: Also make sure all is on the same subnet. This is why you cannot connect.  When you get hooked up LAN to LAN as noted earlier, log into the added router, go to the LAN interface and give it an address on the network (first router)

Comment: Yes but can this work for a WIRELESS connection. There is no cord plugged into the router upstairs other than my computer.

Comment: NVM I looked up WIRELESS Bridges lol I see now, thank you both.

Comment: Yes, the wireless interface is bridged to the lan by default in most third party firmware flavors. Sorry about that, I'm on my phone and must have missed the wireless part in the question. That's usually called client bridged mode in the firmware. The IP subnet concept remains the same

Comment: alright i switched it over and its working... i didn't think it would be that easy...

Comment: Nice, glad you got it going. 

Comment: Would you like to suggest us posting an answer here?

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure all is on the same subnet. This is why you cannot connect. When you get hooked up LAN to LAN as noted earlier, log into the added router, go to the LAN interface and give it an address on the network (first router).  Then all should work.

Comment: Depending on router and firmware, if you have the option also disable the second routers firewall. +1